# Как добавить размер у имеющегося массива

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Всем привет! Сегодня встал вопрос, о добавление к имеющемуся массиву размер. Почитай статьи, я понял, что нужно юзать List, это правильно и удобно, НО у меня всё уже было построено на массивах и если изменять это, то это займёт кучу времени!

НО, я - это гений (сарказм) и у меня получилось добавить к текущему массиву новую ячейку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массивы следует использовать там, где известно количество элементов создаваемой коллекции. Если же количество неизвестно, лучше использовать `List<T>`, потому что он лучше оптимизирован для добавления в него элементов. Технически под списко лежит тот же массив, и он ему так же делает `Array.Resize`, когда ему не хватает место, но он делает это на упреждение, к примеру, в списке менее 16 элементов, а массив там на 16, а когда вы добавляете 17-й элемент, список увеличивает несущий данные массив аж сразу в 2 раза, и так далее. То есть медленное по производительности изменение размеров массива вызывается далеко не каждый раз, когда вы добавляете элемент.

Следовательно, и логика вашего метода расширения массива может быть схожая. Если абстрагироваться от того, что есть в .NET и представить, что существует только массив, то то, чего вы хотели добиться, можно сделать создав свой "список" следующим образом.

```cs
public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[] _array;
    private int _count;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            CheckIndex(index);
            return _array[index];
        }
        set
        {
            CheckIndex(index);
            _array[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count => _count;

    public MyList() : this(16) { }

    public MyList(int count)
    {
        _array = new T[count];
    }

    public MyList(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        _array = source.ToArray();
        _count = _array.Length;
    }

    private void CheckIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _count)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_array.Length == _count)
            Array.Resize(ref _array, _count * 2);
        _array[_count] = item;
        _count++;
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Enumerate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _сount; i++)
            yield return _array[i];
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Этот список может только добавлять и изменять элементы, так же его можно создать на основе любой другой коллекции. Можно и далее его улучшеть, научить его удалять элементы, добавлять сразу по несколько элементов, и так далее. Я написал этот код только ради того, чтобы показать, что если самостояытельно делать "изменяемый" массив, то это может выглядеть как код, представленный выше.

Интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` здесь для того, чтобы с этим списком можно было использовать цикл `foreach` и полезняшки из `System.Linq`. То есть, можно считать, что получилась более-менее полноценная изменяемая коллекция, которая не будет тормозить изменяя размер массива каждый раз при добавлении элемента.

Давайте потестируем, что получилось.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyList<string> list = new MyList<string>();
    list.Add("Раз");
    list.Add("Два");
    list.Add("Три");

    Console.WriteLine($"Количество элементов 'list': {list.Count}");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);

    MyList<int> list2 = new MyList<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        list2.Add(i);

    Console.WriteLine($"Количество элементов 'list2': {list2.Count}");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list2));
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Количество элементов 'list': 3
Раз
Два
Три
Количество элементов 'list2': 20
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Кажется, работает.

Comment: Без интринсиков низачот!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ахаха)

Answer (score 0):

И так, вот мой код:

```
    public string[] addMassiv(string[] old_massiv, int add) //первый параметр - массив, второй - сколько вы хотите добавить ячеек
    {
        string[] new_massiv = new string[old_massiv.Length + add];
        for (int x = 0; x < old_massiv.Length; x++)
            new_massiv[x] = old_massiv[x]; //переписываем старые данные в новый массив
        return new_massiv;
    }
```

Просто подставьте нужный вам тип данных вместо string[]

вот пример использования:

```
string[] sg = new string[1];
sg[0] = "чёто там";
sg = addMassiv(sg, 1);
sg[1] = "чёто там 2";
Console.WriteLine(sg[0] + " " + sg[1]);
```

Comment: [Array.Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-5.0)

Comment: гдеж ты был час назад?

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer оно по сути делает то же самое, что и вы, только быстрее по производительности.

Comment: Свои велосипеды писать полезно. Зато теперь есть опыт и знания, как оно работает внутри.

Comment: Сейчас я окончательно сломаю шаблон, но вместо цикла можно использовать [Array.Copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0).